# How can I format the data that is used by my Virtual PC only?

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

I have Win7 64 bit and I'm running Virtual PC emulating XP at 32 bit.

Problem is that there are program/driver errors on the stuff thats installed on the virtual and I want to format it - but not my main machine (which has lots of valuable data on it).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just perform all your format operations from within Virtual PC. If you can see Virtual PC on the top of the window, you're fine.

Alternatively you could just delete the virtual machine and create a new one.